# How to implement a search feature?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a search feature that allows the user to filter out by products. Typically, I would have the following:

```
// Routes
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      keyword: params.keyword,
      products: this.store.find('product', { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' })
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

In the template:

```
// Template
{{#if products.length}}
  <ul>
    {{#each products}}
      <li>
        Name: {{name}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{else}}
  <p>No products</p>
{{/if}}
```

Which works. However, what if I wanted a search API endpoint to handle filtering of products...

How will the model hook in the routes look like? Should I create an Ember search model? Is that the right approach?

If not, should I be using `Ember.$.ajax` instead? Other approach?

Comment: Aren't you just saying you want to filter products by a certain criterion?  I'm not sure why you'd want to create a different model for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.js` provides facilities to deal with _query_ing data at resource level. Here is a suggested solution followed by some other options that are closer to your expectations.

#### Expected Use Case

1. In Ember, you don't have to map your "representation" of data to your server endpoint. You don't have to be RESTful with your Ember routes (as in URLs).
2. In Ember, one "representation" of data (say a Controller and View set) can consult multiple data sources.
3. Use "q" parameter for full text search on your resource.
4. The point behind all of this is, to decrease complexity of your backend API. If you build a search and query system for *one* resource, you can reuse it for all other resources of your backend.

Create a search URL

```
// in your router
this.route('search')
```

Create a search Route to fetch required data

```
Ember.RSVP.hash({
  stores: this.store.find('store', {
    rate_minimum: 4.0,
    near: 'lat:long',
    q: 'local store name'
  }),

  products: this.store.find('product', {
    price_maximum: '$50',
    near: 'lat:long',
    q: 'famous shoe brand'
  })
});
```

#### Fast Response Way

Use [`Store#pushPayload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload)

Download data with `Ember.$.ajax` from your search endpoint. Keep in mind as long as your data has a name, you can use `Store#pushPayload` to load multiple unrelated data types into Ember Data's Store.

In your Route's `model` hook, use `this.store.all('product')` to return all products in memory without sending a request. At some point in future Ember will update this array. You can use `Ember.RSVP` to "represent" more than one resource.

In your Controller, use array operations like `filterBy` to provide real time update to users' queries beside issuing a new request to API for more relevant data.

This results in immediate response while waiting for backend to reply and immediately updating "representation" of data with backend response.

#### Ember Data-less Way

1. Create a Search Route
2. Use `Ember.$.ajax` to get data
3. Pass it as your Route's `model` hook
4. Send another ajax request whenever user changes search criteria

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would do anything different. When you execute a store.find with query parameters, in your case { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' }, the result that is return by the query is what will show in the controller; assuming you are using an ArrayController. Your model and controller should not need to change, you just control what you want based on how you structure your query.

```
// display all models that are in the store    
store.find('someModel')  

// display a single model   
store.find('someModel', 123) // will display a single model

// display only models that match the query
store.find('someModel', { name: params.keyword, status: 'available' }
```

Now if you are dealing with endpoints that don't conform to the norm, ie. your search endpoints are not just at /products?name=some-name&status=available, then you may have to modify your adapter slightly to deal with the differences. Doing this in the adapter means you still have a simple controller/route/model and you are hiding the complexity which is very specific to the endpoint in the adapter.

Comment: Right, but what if I'm not really after a single model. Lets extend the example above. Lets say my search API endpoint is returning search results from more than one model